# how to hide ACTION and PRINT button for specific group in odoo 14?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, erp, odoo-14

I am working on account.move model and I want to hide PRINT and ACTION button from both tree and form view if the user is not from group **group_cannot_print_delete_journal_entries**.
How can I do that anybody help please.

Comment: [This](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/hide-a-menu-inside-action-button-based-on-condition-168198) might be a good starter for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Default or primary actions like `archive` or `export` are difficult to hide. Archive could be done with setting `groups` on the `active` field in the form view. Export can be done with a [community module](https://github.com/OCA/server-ux/tree/14.0/base_export_manager).

Now to other actions and even printing: You can set security groups in actions (printable reports have this too). Without a group everybody seeing the option to print (eg seeing invoices will show a user the reports to print) can print. When setting a group, only this group is whitelisted to do that. Every other group is automatically blacklisted, except for inheriting groups.

Answer (score 0):

One can also make the action button and print button inivisble using Javascript by passing a context from the act_window

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can include an attribute in your XML to make invisable UI elements. You need to overwrite the XML file in your own module. Here is an example

```
<div class="example" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_already_valid', '=', False)]}">
    Message to hide
</div>
```

As you see, this div will be invisible if the variable is_already_valid is equal to False.
You can download the main Odoo git repo and search by 'invisible' and you will see many examples.

Here is an example using the context instead of a variable

```
invisible="context.get('default_move_type') not in ('out_invoice', 'out_refund','out_receipt')
```

This example is used in account_move.xml
Use the context to get the group you want check and validate that exists